# How to preserve user data from library directory on updating the iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, preserve

According to Apple's iOS Application Programming guide, application preserves ***documents*** and ***library*** directories. My question is what exactly library directory preserves? Does it copy user created files/data (if stored in library directory) as well or just preserves ***Preferences*** and application settings?

My app is  currently storing user data in library directory and users lost their  data on updating to newer version. I want not to happen this again.

Answer (score 1):

User created files and data should be stored in the documents folder. The contents in that folder is also backed up using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Not only should you be saving user data in the documents directory.

```
/**
 Returns the path to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

But you should also only store relative paths to the files located in that directory.  If you store the absolute path, your app won't find the data after an update.

[First App Update, User Data Lost (was stored in Documents directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607655/first-app-update-user-data-lost-was-stored-in-documents-directory/6521499#6521499)