# IOS App on iOS 5 , does the files in app changes when the iphone is upgraded to new version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am writing an IOS App on iOS 5 , does the files in app changes when the iphone OS is upgraded to new IOS. And If Yes How to detect and manage the changes?

could Anyone Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not change. Only Some methods that is not supported with the ugraded OS gets deprecated.

Your Second question, how to detect it?
Here's the answer :

You will get warning at the place where the methods are deprecated.

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: is there any way through programming ,so that the application detects the changes, and identify the deprecated ones?

Comment: yes, as I described in my answer. the warning will come to the specific method, which has deprecated

Comment: doesn't it cause the application to crash ... while the user uses it?

Comment: sometimes it causes, whereas sometimes it doesn't

Comment: By sometimes I meant some methods causes app to crash and rest will not cause a crash, but It won't effect anything in app & that is for sure

Comment: we can use the new methods introduced for the upgraded os.

Comment: can u suggest some document so that i can understand the topic much more?

Comment: Yes, check my second answer given here

Answer (score 0):

No, it's never change when iPhone OS is upgraded to new IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Files stored in the document directory will persist after the app update

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

> `<Application_Home>/Documents/`
>   Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data
>   files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app,
>   such as user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be
>   made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this
>   directory are backed up by iTunes.

Refer below answer for further clarifications
[First App Update, User Data Lost (was stored in Documents directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607655/first-app-update-user-data-lost-was-stored-in-documents-directory)