# Testflight update build will remove datas

Tags: ios, core-data, testflight

I have an application which downloads images/context from server.
Save images to /documents, context to database coredata.

Let say I've downloaded all the datas (app display all the necessary datas (images/context)) and for some reason I uploaded a new build of the app in testflight I then update the app on my device and when I run the app it now won't display the images that I've downloaded on the previous build but I still have the context. So my question is did the new build remove all the datas inside /documents? If so how come I still have my context datas (database coredata)?

Comment: where are you saving the images you downloaded in the previous build?  in the "Cache" folder or?

Comment: save it to documents folder

Answer (score 1):

Is your app utilizing an absolute path to the Documents folder? This is bad, as [recorded here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607655/first-app-update-user-data-lost-was-stored-in-documents-directory).

You would normally want to use something like:

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory
{
    if (_documentsDirectory == nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return _documentsDirectory;
}
```

to get the path dynamically. You could then use the following to log it contents and see what's there:

```
NSArray *documentsDirectory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.dataController.documentsDirectory error:NULL];
NSLog(@"documentsDirectory is: \n%@", [documentsDirectory description]);
```