# UIImage saved to Document Directory returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

NSDocumentDirectoryI'm new to iOS. Im trying to build a simple app to better grasp Core Data and the file system. I can't retrieve data that I've apparently stored.

-I check to see if the file exists at the path, which it does, but when I try to NSLog the data and that returns null.

Any help is much appreciated. My gut is that this is a scoping or memory retention issue but I can't figure it out.

This is the saving method from UIImagePicker

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *imageToAdd = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *pngsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToAdd);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.png",[self getdateAndTime]];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL succcess = [pngsData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"The file exists");
    }

    if (error !=nil) {
        NSLog(@"errorIS %@", error);
    }

    CoreDataStack *cds = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    Photo *photo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:cds.managedObjectContext];
    photo.photoName = filePath;
    [cds saveContext];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

This is the code to retrieve the stored data the Collection View

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCollectionViewCell *photoCell = (PhotoCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Photo *photo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",photo.photoName);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageLocation = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:photo.photoName];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageLocation];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.testImageData];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);

    photoCell.cellImage.image = image;
    photoCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    photoCell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

    return photoCell;
}
```

Comment: FYI - you are mistakenly using the Documentation directory instead of the Documents directory.

Comment: Wow.. thank you for the catch. I fixed it and the problem is still persisting

Comment: Do not check `error` for `!nil`, check the return variable (`success`) for `nil`.

Comment: Note: a simple NSLog of the path by the OP would have shown the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a several issues:

1. <strike>Replace `NSDocumentationDirectory` with `NSDocumentDirectory`.</strike>
2. You are building your paths incorrectly. This:

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.png",[self getdateAndTime]];
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.png", [self getdataAndTime]];
   NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
   ```

   Note the use of `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`. This is important. Without it you end up with:

   > .../sandboxpath/Documentsfilename.png

   instead of:

   > .../sandboxpath/Documents/filename.png

   Make the same fix in both methods.
3. You are saving the fullpath to your `Photo` object. Never save absolute paths. They change over time. Only save the filename relative to `Documents`. So change:

   ```
   photo.photoName = filePath;
   ```

   to:

   ```
   photo.photoName = filename;
   ```

   When you read the value back in the future, append it to the Document path.
4. Your error checking should be:

   ```
   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
       NSLog(@"The file exists");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"errorIS %@", error);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help with explanation. It's very much so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is likely not being found on load because your stored path contains pieces that can change from build to build. Check out this question for a similar issue/result.

[Can't find saved file (in device) after restarting the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848427/cant-find-saved-file-in-device-after-restarting-the-app/27848920?noredirect=1#comment44101789_27848920)

Best answer: don't store the mutable parts; fallback answer: make sure you replace the mutable parts with current values.

Comment: This was actually going to be my next problem to address but rmaddy's fix addressed that as well